# Java handler for JPA managed entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, handler

As I'm new to the topic, the title of my question may be completely wrong- please correct me if needed.

Now to the point:

I have recently made a simple ORM project, that consists of 3 entity classes (Person, Account, PhoneNumber) with some relations.

Right now, I just made a new class ManagedEntity

```
public abstract class ManagedEntity {
    protected int id;
    private Date lastModifDate;
    private String lastModifUser;
}
```

and I have:

Person extends ManagedEntity

Account extends ManagedEntity

PhoneNumber extends ManagedEntity

So far, I have accessed my db using 2 interfaces

1. Person Service (adding, removing, modifying the entities using EntityManager)
2. Query Interface (using criteria queries to get the entities we are looking for)

What I want to do now is add a handler that will fill up the `ManagedEntity` fields on its own, each time when an entity is persisted.

Can anyone tell me how to make an event handler? By which I mean where and what code should I put to "detect" every event of a given type?

Comment: Please ask a specific question as outlined in the [help center.](http://stackoverflow.com/help) Not understanding tutorials is not a specific question.

Comment: I believe I made myself quite clear on what I need, but edited according to Your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your code in a method with `@PrePersist`.

Example tutorial [here](http://timezra.blogspot.fi/2011/10/jpa-callbacks-with-hibernate.html) with a very similar use case.

Comment: And learn to use Google. I can't believe the sad excuses I see here daily, such as "Google had nothing" or "I don't understand the results".

Comment: Far from using excuses like that- mine is simpler- No idea what to look for ;) 

Anyway thanks alot!

Comment: No worries, and I recognize the problem of how to proceed when you're not sure how to formulate the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a call back method on an entity listener associated with a mapped superclass.

Have a look at:

http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/event